# Loopback - Extended AccessToken model not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, passport-facebook

I'm using loopback's passport component with AngularJs frontend. I've created custom model for `User` as `Person` and for `AccessToken` as `PersonAccessToken`.

I'm able to login in correctly through facebook and redirect it to the angularjs client. But what I see is that access tokens are getting stored in built in AccessToken model rather than my custom PersonAccessToken model.
So when I call `Person.logout()` function it throws `500 server error` since it cannot find any access tokens stored.

Person.json:

```
{
"name": "Person",
  "base": "User",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "hasCredentials": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "PersonCredential",
      "foreignKey": "personId"
    },
    "hasIdentities": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "PersonIdentity",
      "foreignKey": "personId"
    },
    "hasAccessToken": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "PersonAccessToken",
      "foreignKey": "personId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

PersonAccessToken.json:

```
{
  "name": "PersonAccessToken",
  "base": "AccessToken",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "belongsToPerson": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": "personId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

model-config.json:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models",
      "./node_modules/loopback-component-passport-c/lib/models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Person": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  },
  "PersonIdentity": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  },
  "PersonCredential": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  },
  "PersonAccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  }
}
```

datasources.json:

```
{
  "db": {
    "name": "db",
    "connector": "memory",
    "file": "db.json"
  }
}
```

and in server.js I've included

```
boot(app, __dirname);

app.middleware('auth', loopback.token({
  model: app.models.PersonAccessToken
}));
```

I don't know what I've been missing or doing wrong? Why is it not storing access tokens in my custom `PersonAccessToken` model?

Comment: Why did you need to extend the `AccessToken` model? Was there something you wanted to add to it?

Comment: @jakerella: In the [loopback-example-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) it uses extended `AccessToken` model and it's working, but here it's not. Why so?

Comment: I'm not sure why it does that, or if you need to. Perhaps you can try without extending the `AccessToken` and just use the built-in version?

Comment: @jakerella: I tried that also, but `Person.logout()` still throws `500 server error`. Is it that extended `User` model does not work with built-in `AccessToken` model? I'm new to this and need help.

Comment: Honestly, I'm just not sure. I haven't used passport with a custom model before.

Comment: Also, I want to note a finding that normal process of signing up new user and login/logout works perfectly on extended models that I've created. But it's not working in the case of passport component.

Comment: Probably too late, but you need to override the relation of the base user, and assign the model of the relation to your custom object.